# Missing value check in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I generated a traffic flow Series like this using pandas package:

```
data = np.array(data)
index = date_range(time_start[0],time_end[0],freq='30S')
s = Series(data, index=index)
```

the sample s output is like this:

```
2013-07-02 10:04:30     13242.0
2013-07-02 10:05:00     12354.3    
...................     .......
```

Here the first column is the index and second column is the value. My task is to collect all moments that their values (second column) are missing.

What I thought is this way:

```
for i in s:
   if isnull(i):
      s.iloc['i']
```

*but 'None' can't be used to reference the index...*

Will this cause efficiency if both missing value and s are large? Is there a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, 5, 6])

In [3]: s.isnull()
Out[3]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

In [4]: s[s.isnull()]
Out[4]: 
3   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64

In [5]: s.index[s.isnull()]
Out[5]: Int64Index([3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the missing value is represented as empty string such as '' or ' '?

Comment: @Jin -- `s.index[s=='']` gives you the indices... [some good tips for working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html)